# set aws route53 as a cname target

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-route53, cname

i have bought a domain, for example **examp.com**, by hoster **x**.
A little bit later i have realized that aws is better for me.
I have register a hosted zone with my domain and change the NS-records by hoster **x** to the NS-Server from my hosted zone.

It works perfect!

But now i would like to whitelabeling my website.

For example a client have a domain **abc.de** and he would like to access my website with a subdomain **sub.abc.de**.
My idea was to create a CNAME-Record on **sub.abc.de** that points to **examp.com**.
But that not work (Not Found - The requested URL was not found on this server.).

I have read that the target server gotta know from the CNAME-Record that points to him. But i don't know how can i do that. In my hosted zone i can only register subdomains for **examp.com** for a ALIAS or so but not for another domain.

Can anybody help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If they control the domain of `abc.de` they are able to create the record their side for `sub.abc.de` as a CNAME record with the value set as your domain (`examp.com`).

They should never be attempting to CNAME to your `NS` server records, these are records for where your DNS records can be retrieved from.

Other than you providing the CNAME value of `examp.com` to them it is upto them to configure their DNS to target your hostname.

Comment: Yes, that not help me. I register the CNAME on sub.abc.de with the value examp.com. But i get "Not Found" if i call sub.abc.de. I have read that the target server from a cname record (examp.com) must know from the source domain. Is that right and if yes, how can i route53 to know about sub.abc.de?

Comment: In this example i have the control over abc.de and examp.com.

Comment: OK sure, Route 53 does not need to know anything about records that are CNAMEing to it. If you add the `sub.abc.de` here: https://toolbox.googleapps.com/apps/dig/. Does it resolve your sub domain?

Comment: Yes, it resolve it to expected examp.com. But why i get Not Found if i call sub.abc.de in my browser?

Comment: This sounds like it is returning 404 from the source app, are you running this on a server or is it running from another AWS service?

Comment: From another aws service. Elastic beanstalk. But why? If i call examp.com directly it works.

Comment: That I do not know, if you perform the DIG command and it resolves down to the IP address of elastic beanstalk then the app is returning a 404. Did you have to specify any whitelisted hostnames within your app (I know some platforms such as Drupal support this functionality)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/218740/discussion-between-chris-williams-and-basti-g).